# JQuery Contact Modal Plugin doesnt run from Visual Studio Casini browser nor IIS

Tags: jquery

Im trying to just run the demo from Visual Studio, with its built-in Casini Browser as well as IIS, and its not firing at all.

However, this DOES work if I just fire-up the HTML from the zip file.

To run the demo doesnt require any web server with PHP enabled because the HTML is modified slightly.

Here is the slightly modified HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> SimpleModal Contact Form </title>
<meta name='author' content='Eric Martin' />
<meta name='copyright' content='2010 - Eric Martin' />

<!-- Page styles -->
<link type='text/css' href='css/demo.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />

<!-- Contact Form CSS files -->
<link type='text/css' href='css/contact.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />

<!-- JS files are loaded at the bottom of the page -->
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
<div id='logo'>
    <h1>Simple<span>Modal</span></h1>
    <span class='title'>A Modal Dialog Framework Plugin for jQuery</span>
</div>
<div id='content'>
    <div id='contact-form'>
        <h3>Contact Form</h3>
        <p>A contact form built on SimpleModal. Demonstrates the use of the <code>onOpen</code>, <code>onShow</code> and <code>onClose</code> callbacks, as well as the use of Ajax with SimpleModal.</p>
        <p>To use: open <code>data/contact.php</code> and modify the <code>$to</code> and <code>$subject</code> values. To enable/disable information about the user, configure the <code>$extra</code> array.</p>
        <p><strong>Note:</strong> This demo must be run from a web server with PHP enabled.</p>
        <input type='button' name='contact' value='Demo' class='contact demo'/> or <a href='#' class='contact'>Demo</a>
    </div>
    <!-- preload the images -->
    <div style='display:none'>
        <img src='images/contact/loading.gif' alt='' />
    </div>
</div>
<div id='footer'>
    &copy; 2010 Eric Martin | <a href='http://www.ericmmartin.com/'>ericmmartin.com</a> | <a href='http://twitter.com/ericmmartin'>@ericmmartin</a> | <a href='http://twitter.com/simplemodal'>@simplemodal</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id='modal-contact-form' style='display:none'>
<div class='contact-top'></div>
<div class='contact-content'>
    <h1 class='contact-title'>Send us a message:</h1>
    <div class='contact-loading' style='display:none'></div>
    <div class='contact-message' style='display:none'></div>
    <form action='#' style='display:none'>
        <label for='contact-name'>*Name:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='name' tabindex='1001' />
        <label for='contact-email'>*Email:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-email' class='contact-input' name='email' tabindex='1002' />
        <label for='contact-subject'>Subject:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-subject' class='contact-input' name='subject' value='' tabindex='1003' />
        <label for='contact-message'>*Message:</label>
        <textarea id='contact-message' class='contact-input' name='message' cols='40' rows='4' tabindex='1004'></textarea>
        <br/>
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type='checkbox' id='contact-cc' name='cc' value='1' tabindex='1005' /> <span class='contact-cc'>Send me a copy</span>
        <br/>
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <button type='submit' class='contact-send contact-button' tabindex='1006'>Send</button>
        <button type='submit' class='contact-cancel contact-button simplemodal-close' tabindex='1007'>Cancel</button>
        <br/>
    </form>
</div>
<div class='contact-bottom'><a href='http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/'>Powered by SimpleModal</a></div>
</div>
<!-- Load JavaScript files -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/contact.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Im not sure how to paste the JQuery JavaScript Files or the large CSS File.  I downloaded them from the demo site.

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/     -- The Contact Modal --

Comment: The Author of the Contact Modal Plugin provided me with updated js files, so now this will run from an .aspx file.  Im not sure what exactly was changed in the .js files, but if someone needs help with that let me know!

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This demo must be run from a web server with PHP enabled.**

Its clearly mentioned that you would require to deploy the demo on a PHP enabled web server.

Comment: Yes but Im only trying to set-up the UI, I # the form action attribute, which you can see in the code.

Comment: It runs when I just double click the .htm from the folder, but when I try to execute this from VisualStudio 2010, the click event doesnt run.

Comment: I tried to run the html file in the folder and clicking on the button doesnt show up any modal. Mainly as the processing of php file being called requires a php server. I would again suggest you try this on a php server.

Comment: Try running the HTML that I posted, with the other files included with the Demo.  I dont have a PHP server, and I cant download that.